# Why is assigning a character in a string to itself a bus error?

Tags: c

This works and produces `bbcd` as I'd expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "abcd";

    string[0] = string[1];

    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

This is a bus error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *string = "abcd";

    string[0] = string[1];

    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Why?

Valgrind says:

```
==9909== Process terminating with default action of signal 10 (SIGBUS)
==9909==  Non-existent physical address at address 0x100000FA2
==9909==    at 0x100000F65: main (test.c:6)
```

Comment: `abcd` is a constant. You can do `char string[5] = "abcd";`instead.

Comment: Please use search before asking questions.

Comment: `char string[] = "abcd";` declares an array and initialises it with `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0' }`. `char *string = "abcd";` declares a pointer to a `char` and initialises it with a pointer to the beginning of the **constant string** `"abcd"`. You can change the array you declared, but modifying a constant string leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @2501 ["char bus error"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=char+bus+error) turns up a lot of unrelated things. Thanks for pointing out the dup.

Comment: @PaulRooney can you show some reference to your comment?

Comment: @2501 C has oh so many fascinating traps and pitfalls.

Comment: @PaulRooney Type of a string literal is `char[*]`.

Comment: @PaulRooney I tried `cc -Weverything -pedantic -std=c99 test.c` and no warnings.

Comment: @Schwern Yes. The moto is: don't assume anything.

Comment: @Schwern Add the flag `-Wwrite-strings` (if clang supports it).

Comment: @2501 Of course! `-Wall` isn't all so why would `-Weverything` be everything? \*sigh\* It didn't catch it. I got a warning about my lack of `const` which might have at least been a hint. "*initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char [5]' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]*" (I only sat down and properly learned C last winter)

Comment: @Schwern You shouldn't ignore that warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127353/discussion-between-schwern-and-2501).

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second case, you're trying to modify a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in the second case, `string[0]` is the first element of the string literal, and any assignment to that is an attempt to modify the value held by that element.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *"String literals"*

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.